# Error in openning a file in R with two different method

Tags: r

I have trouble opening a file in R with the following `for` loop :

```
#Counting the number of files in the folder
num_files <- length(list.files("C:/Users/Jane/Downloads/WantedFolder"))
num_files

#File extraction from the folder
a<-list.files("C:/Users/Jane/Downloads/Folder")

for (i in 1:num_files){
    g<-a[i]
    data1<-read.table(g)
    head(data1)
}
```

To me it should be working as the classic `read.table` :

```
data1<-read.table("C:/Users/Jane/Downloads/WantedFolder/WantedFile.txt")
```

I got the following error and don't understand why since I've checked the directory several times and it is working for the "classic" `read.table`

```
Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'WantedFile.txt': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Try to replace `read.table("g")` by `read.table(g)`. You might also need to do `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files` if files are not in working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your working directory, which you can check using `getwd()`. `list.files` only returns the names of the files in a folder, not their full path. Based on the error, it seems like you are trying to open a file called `"wantedfile.txt"` in your current working directory. To avoid R assuming your current working directory, you can specify the absolute path like so:

```
path <- "C:/Users/Jane/Downloads/Folder"
a <- list.files(path)
a <- file.path(path, a)
```

This pastes the absolute path of the wanted folder to the file names returned by `list.files`-

Comment: You can also use `a <- list.files(path, full.names=T)`